# Does WSL use LF line endings or CRLF line endings?

Tags: git, command-line, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Unix uses LF line endings.
Windows uses CRLF line endings.
What about WSL?

Comment: WSL is Linux (which isn't Unix), or rather, it hosts actual Linux distributions. When you install Ubuntu, you install Ubuntu and run Ubuntu, not something like Ubuntu

Comment: Why are you asking? You could answer the question yourself just by checking a text file. Did you encounter some problem and assumed that WSL uses CR+LF ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question doesn't really have an answer, because operating systems don't use line endings, *applications* use line endings. Most OS APIs provide the contents of a file to an application as a continuous stream of bytes, not a collection of lines, so it is up to the application to read and write line endings according to whatever algorithm it wants.

The *convention* on Windows (and before that, MS-DOS) was for applications to indicate line endings with a CR LF pair, while the *convention* on Unix (and related systems such as Linux) was for applications to use just an LF.

Modern applications are generally capable of reading and writing either format - that includes Notepad in up to date versions of Windows - but may pick a default based on these historical conventions.

Since applications running under WSL are the same as they would be running under a real Linux system, they will probably default to LF.

Comment: Even the *kernel* (which is probably the smallest part that could be called "the operating system") uses LF. For example for files in the `/proc` file system that represent human-readable data. Similarly the `binfmt` module which handles Hash-bang lines will read until the first LF. So while it's *mostly* just convention, it's *sometimes* more than that and even if it's just convention, it's followed *very strongly*. So IMO the shortcut "Unix uses LF" is close enough to the truth to be acceptable.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Those are good examples, but I still think the shorthand is misleading, because it leads to confused questions like this one. The chances that the OP is going to poke around in /proc on their WSL system are tiny; much more likely they're going to edit something in nano or vim, and run it with PHP or Python. Those are all going to cope with CR LF just fine, even if they are configured to default to LF.

Comment: Operating Systems *do* have line ending conventions. For instance, when Linux writes /proc files with line endings, it emits "\n" at the end of lines. Built-in Windows methods that understand a concept of line-endings generally emit/expect/handle \r before \n.

Comment: After that, it is up to applications to adhere to the local convention, often facilitated by either kernel facilities or standard runtime libraries (libc, stdc++, etc). An application *can* violate the newline conventions, because they're merely conventions, but that's a bug, not a feature.

This is why C++ iostreams have `std::endl`, for instance.

Comment: @kfsone I already responded to a comment about /proc two years ago, and I stand by that comment; and my answer already says that operating systems have *conventions*; so I'm not sure what new point you're trying to make.

Comment: @IMSoP Unfortunately you're thinking thru layers of software intended to abstract/obscure the local operating system. So to you, they seem like optional conventions. Let's try something a little less heavily engineered to obfuscate platform specifics shall we? `docker run --rm -it alpine` `apk add apk3 && python3 -c 'open("test.py", "wb", 0x777).write("#! /usr/bin/env python3\r\nprint(\"hello\")\r\n")' && ./test.py` which outputs `': No such file or directory` because the os's own line-buffered mode uses the os's own convention.

Comment: @kfsone Again, you're repeating an example from the comment I already responded to - the `binfmt` handler detects files beginning with the bytes `0x23 0x21`, and loads until the next occurrence of the byte `0x0a`. Maybe it makes use of some shared function for seeking that `0x0a` byte, but that shared function is no more "the real OS" than any other; it is entirely up to *every piece of software* whether it uses that shared function, or one which requires an `0x0d 0x0a` sequence, or one which treats them as equivalent.

Comment: PHP and Python disprove your argument, it wasn't THAT long ago that neither language wasted the cpu cycles to cope with '\r' in non-windows binaries. Virtualization, faster CPUs, better string manipulation instructions at the machine level, and things like wsl finally made the overhead worth the price. But it's certainly not free to implement. consider: `char *p = strchr(start, '\n'); if (p > start && *(p-1) == '\r') --p;` or worse `auto eol = in.find_first_of("\r\n"); ... ; start = eol; if (in[start] == '\r') start++;`.

Comment: The OP isn't asking about applications running under WSL, but about WSL, which is a linux kernel emulation/layer running on Windows. If you don't understand kernels, that may be why you're confused.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're saying that the kernel doesn't do any file io itself, or if it does, what, does it call out to python to do it? Is that it? If the kernel is going to read something from /dev, will it handle `char[3] {'1', '\r', '\n'}` and `char[2] {'1', '\n'}` indistinguishably? Of course, if the kernel DID do that, then the correct description of the linux line ending convention would be '\r?\n' and not '\n'.

Comment: @kfsone Functions used by applications (including the implementation of higher-level languages) are not part of the kernel, they are part of *standard libraries*, chosen at compile- or link-time. Here's the documentation for [the various ways to get a line of text in glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html). I can't be bothered to track it down, but I rather suspect PHP had to go out of its way to _implement_ `\r\n` lines, rather than relying on the facilities in glibc which only handle `\n`, *completely independent of where the program is run*.

Comment: The Linux kernel absolutely has an opinion on what a line separator is: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L1408

It doesn't emit \r\n, \n\r, \f, or 127. It expects in kernel or userspace usage to consume and emit ASCII codepoint 10 as a line separator. To be agnostic, the kernel would need explicit code that says "or \r".

Here's the kernel looking for a newline: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c664e16bb1ba1c8cf1d7ecf3df5fd83bbb8ac15a/kernel/ksysfs.c#L77. Doesn't check for '\r'.

Comment: @kfsone I honestly don't care if you can find me twenty-two functions which happen to be shipped as part of the kernel and do some text processing; they are not the functions people are talking about when they say **the OS as a whole** uses particular line endings. What people are talking about is **what they see in the applications they use every day**, and none of that is part of the kernel, it's in standard libraries, and in individual applications following a convention.

Comment: @IMSoP You can write a library that uses any line ending you want, that doesn't define what the operating system's native line endings are, the kernel does. You're thinking that `char(0x0a)` means "line ending", but that's only true in an ASCII environment.

ASCII(0x0a) is a teletype character meaning "line feed" or advance line without moving the print head horizontally. Unix OSes saved us all a byte by deciding that unlike other OSes they wouldn't require {13,10} in input as line termination, so they could use strchr instead of strstr.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: You say: Operating systems don't use line-endings. I've demonstrated from the kernel down to shells down to applications that they do. You make the claim that they don't out of ignorance and inexperience. Lots of applications *support* '\n' as a line terminator because you can get away with it so long as you have a deeper understanding of why all your lines suddenly have surprise '\r's at the beginning if you load a MacOS file or appear as one long line if you load an old MacOS, a Big5-encoded file, or a QNX text file.

More importantly - WSL does EOL translation in some scenarios.

Comment: @kfsone I am not saying that "no part of an operating system uses line endings"; I am saying that "every part of an operating system that uses line endings has to make its own decision on how to do so". I know perfectly well what the different characters are, and the **conventions** of where they're used. But the vast majority of programs are **not** using the kernel's definition of "line", or anything else "provided by the operating system"; they are using a (portable!) standard C function, or an ad hoc implementation, and **deciding to follow the convention common on their target OS**.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html - specifically, the 'b'.

https://gist.github.com/kfsone/deaf8db98976f2f9e319570ad78911d2

WSL is linux, so WSL uses linux line endings. If you create files using normal tools in ~/ under WSL they will have POSIX \x0a line endings. If you read the output of WSL tools in binary form they'll have \x0a line endings.

Running "git diff" from win vs wsl on the same repository directory will produce different results unless you specifically tune the config in each environment.
https://gist.github.com/kfsone/dc2a6e1035a79920807786968b247707

Comment: Well written, truly portable, good-citizen applications ought to not care. But the vast majority of libraries/apps, especially CLI/wsl-facing ones, just don't.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7NqY.png
Python, in linux, and thus under wsl, doesn't expect the \rish imposition. And performa hacks often decide that they don't want an extra in-case-it-came-from-dos branch in a hot-path loop killing performance for that one win/mac user who isn't unaware but somehow manages to set their editor up to only add \r on the lines they modify...

Comment: @kfsone Feel free to write your own answer which you think explains things better. This is not a forum, and I'm not going to be drawn into point by point discussion of every random example you think of.